# Contador Jquery

Tags: jquery

Boa noite, alguém poderia me auxiliar em uma dúdiva.

Cada Vez que a pessoa clicar no BOTÃO é chamado a função:

```
function cloneDivDescricaoProduto() {
    var count  = 0;
    count++;
    console.log(count);
    var html_corpo = '<div class="form-group col-md-3"><label for="descricao">Qual seria o tamanho ?</label><input name="data[Tamanho]['+ count+'][descricao]" class="form-control" id="descricao" placeholder="Ex: Pequena, Media, Grande" type="text"></div>'+$(".criarCloneDescricao").html()+'</div>'
    $(".criarCloneDescricao").html(html_corpo);
}
```

E nessa função ao ser chamada eu gostaria que executasse o contador porem sempre ao clicar ele me retorna 1 no console.
Qual seria o resultado esperado: Ao clicar no botão chamar a função `cloneDivDescricaoProduto()` e o contador ir incrementando a cada click e acrescentando na variável contador na div criada.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Em si, você toda vez que chama a função está criando a variável contador do 0. Você não está salvando o valor dessa variável fora do escopo da função.

Você pode solucionar esse problema criando a variável count fora dessa função, dessa forma toda vez que a função for executada a variável não vai ser recriada

```
var count  = 0;

function cloneDivDescricaoProduto() {
 count++;
 console.log(count);
 var html_corpo = '<div class="form-group col-md-3"><label for="descricao">Qual seria o tamanho ?</label><input name="data[Tamanho]['+ count+'][descricao]" class="form-control" id="descricao" placeholder="Ex: Pequena, Media, Grande" type="text"></div>'+$(".criarCloneDescricao").html()+'</div>'
 $(".criarCloneDescricao").html(html_corpo);
}
```